# The data is different when a string is stored and when a number is stored in the assembly

Tags: debugging, assembly, reverse-engineering

I was solving the wargame problem, and there was a phrase that entered serial.

If you type the number 12345 in the serial column, the eax register contains 0x3039, which means the decimal number 12345.
[image]

However, if you enter the string "whatisserial" in the serial column, the eax contains a value of 0x9FEBEBAA. This is 2683038634 in decimal, so what is the association between this number and the string "whatiserial"? Is it just the price of garbage?
[image]

When I approached the address value, not the value, there was nothing.

Comment: A value in a register after typing stuff in has to come from other software instructions but you didn't show any.  String->int doesn't happen in one instructions. It's not any of the ASCII bytes of the string (https://www.asciitable.com/). My other guess was going to be a pointer to something, but you say there's nothing at that address. Without the code to see how EAX is set, nothing we can really tell you.  Another possibility is that it's the result of decimal-string->int conversion using `total = total*10 + (digit - '0')`  iterated over the string of ASCII characters (truncated to 32-bit).

Comment: Try putting w, h a, t, i, s, s, e, r, i, a, l, through what Peter said `total = total*10 + digiit - '0`'.  Or maybe use a smaller test example, one or two characters..

Comment: thanks so much When I looked at the function before eax, there was a specific syntax.